# In node.js mongo collection.find() is not returning all documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb

1. I have simple collection that contains 161 documents only
2. Mongo shell returns all 161 docs when I execute the following, No Issues.

   ```
    db.responses.find({}, {limit:1000})
   ```
3. But from inside my node.js code, it limits the documents to 101. My code is part of the large project code and tried finding the config on the driver or cursor but none. I changed my code as follows but mongo does not seem to honor and returns null data, when it crosses the 101 limit and my code breaks.

   ```
    db.responses.find().limit(1000).maxTimeMS(30*1000);
   ```

I'm new to both mongo and node; after spending hours, I seek help to see if something is missed.

Comment: You should provide you code here, maybe even reduce the offending file to a minimal working example.

Comment: Here is the trimmed snippet of the large file. Please see if this helps to identify where the miss is.

Comment: Here is the trimmed snippet of the large file. Please see if this helps to identify where the miss is.
      MongoClient.connect(config.mongoUrl, function(err, client) {
       partialQueryMatchCursor = collection.find().limit(1000).maxTimeMS(30*1000);
       fullQueryMatchCursor =  collection.find({query:userQueryTrimmed});
       if{ code ok
       }  
       else
       {
        partialQueryMatchCursor.toArray(function(err, docs){
         console.log(docs.length); //error! access property of null
         
         while(){        
          //code ok
         }
        });